# Navigating different table-cell to different UIVewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am sorry for echoing same question but after a lot of time spending I could not figure out the issue.

Suppose, a **UITableView** have **2 table_cell** s and I want to navigate **different UIViewController** from **each table_cell**. How do I do that?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

                if indexPath.row == 0 {

                    // go to DetailVC_1

                } else if indexPath.row == 1 {

                    // go to DetailVC_2

        }
```

[image]

Comment: try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014001/how-to-push-a-new-view-controller-when-a-table-cell-is-tapped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either present a new view controller manually:

```
self.presentViewController(controller, animated:true, completion:nil)
// or push on a navigation controller
self.navigationController.pushViewController(controller, animated:true)
```

Or perform a segue you set up in a storyboard earlier. (Drag from the view controller to another view controller in your storyboard).

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MyIdentifier", sender: self)
```

When using storyboards you can also use multiple cell types and setup a segue from each cell type to a new controller. This way the new controller will be presented automatically. The only code you might need to use in that case would be a `prepareForSegue` method where you pass the correct information to the presented controller before the segue is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("firstViewController", sender: self)
} else if indexPath.row == 1 {
         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("secondViewController", sender: self)
}
```

If you have several view controllers, you can call them `viewController0` and `viewController1` etc. Then you can have a string `"viewController" + String(indexPath.row)`. Hope this helps.